# Creating Relationships

Tags: neo4jclient

I've been battling this for two days and am at a loss. I'm attempting to create node relationships and am severely failing.

Here is my code for creating and running the relationship.

```html
var query = graphClient.Cypher
  .Match("(apt_1:AttackPatterns)", "(apt_2:AttackPatterns)")
  .Where((AttackPatterns apt_1) => apt_1.Id == Convert.ToInt64(apt.ID))
  .AndWhere((AttackPatterns apt_2) => apt_2.Id == Convert.ToInt64(rt.Relationship_Target_ID))
  .CreateUnique("(apt_1)-[:" + rtrn.ToString() + "]->(apt_2)");

query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Here is the AttackPatterns class.

```html
public class AttackPatterns
{
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

During runtime, the value for query equates, in one iteration, to the following:

MATCH (apt_1:AttackPatterns), (apt_2:AttackPatterns)\r\nWHERE (apt_1.Id = \"1\")\r\nAND (apt_2.Id = \"122\")\r\nCREATE UNIQUE (apt_1)-[:ChildOf]->(apt_2)

I notice the "\r\n" characters. I also notice quotes around 1 and 122. When I paste this into the Neo4j web interface replacing "\r\n" with actual new lines and remove the "\" escape character before the quotes, it fails. If I remove the quotes around the 1 and 122, it successfully creates the relationship.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any assistance!

Comment: What type is `rt`?, and is `apt` an `AttackPatterns`?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some assumptions about types, as I *think* I know what's going on - basically - the `Convert.ToInt64` **isn't** called before the query is made, you have to do it outside of the query generation:

```
//Given:
var apt = new { ID = "1" };

//Convert outside query
var ap1Id = Convert.ToInt64(apt.ID);

//Use in query
var query = gc.Cypher
    .Match("(apt_1:AttackPatterns)", "(apt_2:AttackPatterns)")
    .Where((AttackPatterns apt_1) => apt_1.Id == ap1Id) // <-- using locally created var
/* etc */
```

The `\r\n` is just for formatting when you look at the `DebugQueryText` property, they're not sent across, the only problem is the `"` around the numbers.

Please feel free to add this as a bug to the github project and I'll have a look into it, ideally it would be executed beforehand, but it's possibly like this for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Chris. If it gives any more insight, I tried the following code that ended up working:

Comment: var query = graphClient.Cypher

.Match("(apt_1:AttackPattern)", "(apt_2:AttackPattern)")
.Where("apt_1.Id = {id1}")
.WithParam("id1", Convert.ToInt64(apt.ID))
.AndWhere("apt_2.Id = {id2}")
.WithParam("id2", Convert.ToInt64(rt.Relationship_Target_ID))
.CreateUnique("(apt_1)-[:" + rtrn.ToString() + "]->(apt_2)");

Comment: Cool, the `WithParam` call evaluates it as you'd expect, which is nicer than my version ;)